# Diff command to compare files on different servers--Unix

Tags: linux, unix, diff

Can I use the diff command to compare files on two different servers?
If not, is there any other option?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can copy the file over from the other server using `scp` and then use `diff`.

Or `ssh` to the remote host and `diff` using a single command like this:

```
ssh user@remote "cat /path/to/remote/file" | diff - /path/to/local/file
```

Comment: Just wanted to make sure if the first solution is an optimized solution when we are trying to compare bulk files on both servers? Wouldn't it load the source server with the files copied from the destination server?

Answer (score 12):

I know it's a late answer but I take the question literally, no local file and **two remote files**.
In `bash` (and not only) it's possible to use the *process substitution* <sup>[[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html),[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)]</sup> `<(...)`:

```
diff <(ssh Server1 'cat /path/to/file1') <(ssh Server2 'cat /path/to/file2')
```

> The process `<(list)` is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename.

**Note**

- Of course if you need only one remote file you can put the local file instead one of the `<(...)`.
- If both files are on the same server you can use a simpler

  ```
  ssh Server1 'diff /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2'
  ```

Answer (score 11):

If your comparing multiple files, then look up [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) and [rdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff), which save you the bandwidth of copying all files.

Btw, if your files are very large, then please update your question with that information.

Answer (score 5):

The "-" diffs against STDIN. You can do something like this:

```
ssh server 'cat file_to_diff' | diff -u localfile -
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're troubleshooting AWS instance then it may make sense to stop inatanceA then attach its drive to instanceB you're want to compare with.